# cocos-2d:My app crashes when i close it via task manager

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have Weird problem,When i close my app via task manager , my app gets crashed on the line

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

throwing **"Thread : 1 signal SIGKILL"** error,and i can't reopen my app at all. other times it works pretty well.
Please some one help me with this problem.
I am new to cocos-2d so please be gentle :( , thanks.

Comment: `Application does not run in background:YES` if you have this key setup in your info.plist, remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is normal, expected behavior. The reason it seems weird, I think, is that when you run from Xcode, your executable is attached to the debugger in Xcode, so it sometimes prevents things from executing (for example, in a crash or SIG_KILL scenario). This is just giving you a hint as to what apple is doing when you use the task-bar to close the app... it sends SIGKILL to the process :-)

EDIT: for the curious, I tested a little and found that `applicationWillTerminate:` is not called first, which is actually encouraging as a consumer of apps. You really are SIGKILLing these things. I think this means (with the background-processing workflow) that the only case when that method will be called is if you [opt out of background execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5). The good news is that in order to kill an app this way, you need to move it to the background first, so the canonical place for teardown is applicationWillResignActive: *but you knew that...*

EDIT: instructions for avoiding the can't-run-again issue:

1. Build and Run the app on your device from Xcode
2. As soon as the app is "up and running", click "stop" in Xcode
3. When the app has closed, it is now "detached" from Xcode and you can terminate it and re-open as often as you wish. Just keep in mind that it will no longer log to Xcode any NSLog calls or otherwise.

Comment: I am really noob , i can't really get you :( am so sorry ..can u explain me in simpler way ,thanks..is there any remedy for this problem,,,,but if i close other app in task manager its working fine

Comment: What I mean is, this is not actually a problem. Xcode is trying to be helpful. I edited my answer to show you how to get the app to be terminable/re-openable